# For what is this line for?

Tags: php

I am working on a template a friend given me ages ago. However, this is the code of the main page:

```
<div class="span4">
                    <div class="widget">
                        <div class="navbar"><div class="navbar-inner"><h6>fame</h6></div></div>
                        <div class="well body">
                            <center>
                            <div class="fame">
                                <?php include("cache/fame.php"); ?>
                            </div>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

In this fame.php, there's a line of code:

```
    if(!isset($_GET['enable']) && !isset($argv[1]) == "enable")
{
    echo 'Invalid request';
    return;
}
```

And it always return Invalid request from the main page.. So, what is this last code paragraph for?

Comment: `isset` is not use for comparison `!isset($argv[1]) == "enable"`

Comment: `!isset($argv[1]) == "enable"` using loosly comarpison with  a boolean and a string doesn't make much sense

Comment: It's not written by me, I just want to know what this paragraph does (or what I am doing wrong) in order to fix it ^^

Comment: isset test if an variable is set it return true or false, $_GET['enable'] requier "?enable=" in uri to be set

Comment: so it must be ?enable=true ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if(!isset($_GET['enable']) && !isset($argv[1]) == "enable")
{
    echo 'Invalid request';
    return;
}
```

The above code is used in 2 scenarios: 
One is the script mode for which the argument $argv is used.
Second mode is as server code where Global params are being passed i.e $_GET.

Just change the code to handle both the scenarios.

```
if(php_sapi_name() == 'cli' && (!isset($argv[1]) || ( isset($_GET['enable']) && $argv[1] !== "enable"))

{
    echo 'Invalid request';
    return;
}
else
{    
 if(!isset($_GET['enable']) 
 {
    echo 'Invalid request';
    return;
 }
}
```

Comment: So in your if-statement, $_GET['enable'] must be set AND also $argv[1] must be set, to not echo "Invalid request". This does not make any sense to me..